# Remittance to India from US in an Indian account?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, non-resident

I am Indian citizen working in the US on a non-immigrant work visa. I have a regular savings account in India as well but I dont have an NRE/NRO account. So, will my remittance send to India account be taxable? I have already paid taxes on my income in the US.

Answer (score 1):

Tax does not depend on whether you transfer the funds to India or keep in US.

If you have spent less than 182 days in a given financial year, then you are treated as "Non-Resident" [NRI] in India. If you are NRI, you need not pay tax for income earned outside India. If you are NRI, you should not be holding Savings account these need to be converted into NRO.

If you have spent more than 182 days in a given financial year in India, you are "Resident" and have to pay tax on your Global Income [whether you transfer funds to India or Not is not relevant]. You can claim the rebate to the extent of taxes paid in US.